# Call Javascript function in Servlet, after servlet responce

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page. There is a form in the jsp page and when I press submit the control goes to the servlet and the servlet sends the response in the same jsp. I want to call a javascript fuction after the response is called.

```
String operation = request.getParameter("operation");
        if (operation.equals("create")) {
            String value = null;
            Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
            String entity = request.getParameter("entity");
            Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
            while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
                if (paramName.equals("operation") || paramName.equals("entity")) {
                    value = request.getParameter(paramName);
                } else {
                    value = Constraints.toTitleCase(request.getParameter(paramName));
                }
                requestMap.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("{KeY} :"+k+".....{VAlue} :"+v));
                requestMap.put(paramName, value);
            }
            masterHelper.processRequest(requestMap);
            log.debug("js");
            response.getOutputStream().println("<script>sucess();('hello');</script>");
            response.sendRedirect("user/master/" + entity + ".jsp");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are redirecting the page .

```
response.sendRedirect("user/master/" + entity + ".jsp");
```

try sending the function definition also.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is use just set extra variable for it and then based on the value of that variable call the javascript function. You can follow steps below

1. In your servlet set a boolean variable

   > boolean isResponse=true;
2. Then add it to your response

   > request.setAttribute("isResponse", isResponse);
3. the add below code in your jsp.

   > ${ isResponse=="true"?'windows.onLoad=functionname()':'' }

And you are done with it.